# Where to start encrypting a user password?

Tags: encryption

I have an issue when it comes to encrypting user passwords. I have a authorization services with which one can create a user account. Given is an `email` and a `password`. As for now I encrypt the user password in the server before persisting it in the database.

However I feel that is somewhat wrong because the password is in plaintext when coming in through a https request. So I actually could log the real passwords of users.

Isn't that a dangerous way to handle user passwords? I think it would be better to encrypt user passwords in the client side code (javascript) before submitting a form (either registration or login). So the password will arrive encrypted already.

Am I right with my concerns?

Comment: Encrypting passwords client side just makes the encrypted password, the password. If you find this encrypted password in a log, you can just log in with it (without the encrypting step).

Comment: Why do you have a user password at all? What does your service use the user's password for? If it's to authenticate to the service then you **not** encrypt the password, you should hash it per gusto2's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I encrypt the user password in the server before persisting it in the database.

Please don't. Use slow salted hash if possible (BCrypt, SCrypt, Argon2,..)

If you really cannot use the mentioned functions, than a database native hashing  functionality is better than encryption.

https://practice-code.github.io/architecture/how-to-store-passwords-in-a-secure-way/

> the password is in plaintext when coming in through a https request

Nope, the https encrypts traffic between the client (browser) and the server.

Yes you can see the password in the browser side before encryption (but the user entered the password, so it looks ok to access its own data) and the server needs to validate the password anyway.

> Isn't that a dangerous way to handle user passwords?

Indeed. So maybe it's a good idea to offload the user authentication to already proven services (AWS Cognito, IBM AppID, Azure AD,..) or to social accounts (Google, FB,..)

> I think it would be better to encrypt user passwords in the client side code

As already commented, that is  not helping at all. Then the encrypted value becomes the password

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is in clear text when using HTTPS, data is encrypted that is the main point of using server certificate !

As an alternative approach usually one stores the password hash in db instead of the password text, so eventually your code uses hash algorithm to generate the password hash and compare it versus one stored in DB, by that even if someone was able to access the database records ,that one is unable to figure out what is the password because all he gets is the hash value

[Using Hash in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/dotnet/csharp/compute-hash-values)